# Как сократить слово «коммерческий»?

Tags: сокращения

Как правильно сократить слово «коммерческий» — ком. или комм.?

Например в контексте «коммерческая маржа».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно: ***коммерч.***

[**Сокращение слов и словосочетаний**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/docs?layout=item&id=16_15)

6.1. Прилагательные и причастия, оканчивающиеся на:  ...**-еский**...

сокращают отсечением этой части слова.